# Rails 4: Add Multiple Columns to Existing Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know how to add one column to an existing table. Now I have to add many columns to an existing table. Is there a shorter way for:

```
add_col1_col2_col3_col4_.._coln_to_tables col1:integer col2:integer etc...
```

Do I have to do the above for ALL the additional columns I have to add?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No not necessary. You can do

Assuming TableName is user

```
rails g migration AddColumnsToUser col1:integer col2:integer .. etc.
```

Comment: Can you specify things like integer arrays? `add_column :disciplines, :days, :integer, array: true`

Answer (score 21):

Here's a good resource on [ActiveRecord:Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) which lists all the commands you can use to manipulate your databases. You can also do the task this way:

`rails g migration AddMoreColumnsToModel`

Then open the migration file and put:

```
def change
  add_column :table, :new_column, :type
  # add as many columns as you need 
end
```

If you wanted to do what Maxd suggests, having literally 100 columns of the same type auto-create, his code is a good idea.

Answer (score 11):

Just create migration and generate these columns i.e.:

```
class ChangeTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :tables do |t|
      100.times do |i|
        t.integer :"column_#{i}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to above answers but for understanding purpose hope below naming convention is good.

```
rails g migration add_first_column_and_second_column_to_model first_column:string second_column:string
```

Answer (score 1):

This migration file can be done in a loop.
But do you really want to do this? It does not look correct to create such a heavy model to hold everything.

Answer (score 0):

command to create `new model` and `table` with `columns`:

```
rails g model ModelName col_name1:string col_name2:integer col_name3:text ...
```

command to add more `columns` under existing table:

```
rails g migration AddColumnToModelName col_name4:string col_name5:integer ...
```

At last, run `migration` by command:

```
rake db:migrate
```